# Nhibernate QueryOver Enum Flags

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Trying to use QueryOver and a flagged enum query. This works in Nhibernate.Linq:

```
var results = repo.Query()
  .Where(x => (x.Classification & LineItemClassification.Shipping) == LineItemClassification.Shipping);
```

This throws `Could not determine member from (Convert(x.Classification) & 2)` using QueryOver:

```
 var results = repo.QueryOver()
   .Where(x => (x.Classification & LineItemClassification.Shipping) == LineItemClassification.Shipping);
```

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum LineItemClassification
{
        Foo,
        Widget,
        Shipping
}
```

Mapping:

```
Map(x => x.Classification)
  .CustomType<LineItemClassification>();
```

Comment: Does casting x.Classification to an int work?

Comment: Any luck figuring this out? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: @mxmissile I have exactly same problem. What do you do for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue today and ended up doing a SQL projection. Not ideal, as it moves us away from the type safety that we get with the QueryOver API, but it works. The relevant portion of my code follows.

```
.QueryOver<ProjectActivity>()
.Where(Expression.Gt(Projections.SqlProjection(String.Format("({{alias}}.ProjectActivityTypeId & {0}) as ProjectActivityTypeId", (int)type), null, null), 0))
```

Hope that helps.